# Passing child variable to parent constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I'm trying to pass a variable from parent class to it's child class.
The code does compile, but keeps giving me the result; 0.
When I hardcode the value in the base constructor inside the child class, it does give me the wanted result.

Parent class.h:

```
class Parent{
 float price;

public:
 Parent(float price)
}
```

Parent class.cpp:

```
 #include "Parent.h"

 Parent::Parent(float price){
 this->price = price;
 }
```

Child class.h:

```
 class Child : Parent{
 const float price = 0.29;

 public:
 Child();
 }
```

Child class.cpp:

```
#include "Child.h"

Child::Child() : Parent(price){
}
```

How can I make it so the var inside the child class can be used in the constructor of the base class?

Comment: It does not sadly enough, when I type Child::Child() : Parent(0.29){} it works..

Comment: You could [pass a parameter to the parent constructor from the child constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585856/pass-parameter-to-base-class-constructor-while-creating-derived-class-object#comment23835887_16585856).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the [initialization order](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order) is:

> The order of member initializers in the list is irrelevant: the actual
>   order of initialization is as follows:
>
> ...
>
> - 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as they appear in this class's base-specifier list
> - 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of declaration in the class definition.
>
> ...

The base subobjects are always initialized before data members; that means when you're trying to pass the data member `Child::price` to the constructor of the base class `Parent`, it's not initialized yet.

Comment: That makes sense, how could I make this work in my solution?

Comment: @MrEmper As the workaround you can pass `0.29` directly, or make it `static` if the value is the same for all the instances, then you can use it to pass to the constructor of `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using `static` you can do the following:

```
// Child.h
class Child : Parent {
    static const float price;

 public:
    Child();
};
// Child.cpp
const float Child::price = 0.29;
```

This code will work as intended.